# How do I fix this problem it say's 'queryForObject(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[], java.lang.Class<T>)' is deprecated

Tags: java-11, jdbctemplate, spring-boot-maven-plugin, implements, postgresql-14

I'm not sure how to fix this since I just started doing spring boot project last Thursday. Unfortunately today is the deadline of my project so frankly I'm quite panicking right now :/

**Here is my sample problem code:**

```
@Override
public Integer getCountByEmail(String email) {
    return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(SQL_COUNT_BY_EMAIL, new Object[]{email}, Integer.class);
}

@Override
public User findById(Integer userId) {
    return null;
}
```

**Here is the overall code of the Java Class:**

```
package com.example.Spring.boot.Repositories;

import com.example.Spring.boot.Entity.User;
import com.example.Spring.boot.Exceptions.EtAuthException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.GeneratedKeyHolder;
import org.springframework.jdbc.support.KeyHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.Statement;

@Repository
public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository {

private static final String SQL_CREATE = "INSERT INTO SB_USERS(USER_ID, 
FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL," +`"PASSWORD) VALUES(NEXTVAL('SB_USERS_SEQ'), ?, ?, ?, ?)";`
private static final String SQL_COUNT_BY_EMAIL = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SB_USERS WHERE EMAIL = ?";
private static final String ID = "SELECT USER_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL, PASSWORD " +`"FROM SB_USERS WHERE USER_ID = ?";`
       
@Autowired
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Override
public Integer create(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String password) throws EtAuthException {
    try {
        KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
        jdbcTemplate.update(connection -> {
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_CREATE, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            ps.setString(1, firstName);
            ps.setString(2, lastName);
            ps.setString(3, email);
            ps.setString(4, password);
            return ps;
        }, keyHolder);
        return (Integer) keyHolder.getKeys().get("USER_ID");
    }catch (Exception e) {
        throw new EtAuthException("Invalid details. Failed to create account");
    }
}

@Override
public User findByEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) throws EtAuthException {
    return null;
}

@Override
public Integer getCountByEmail(String email) {
    return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(SQL_COUNT_BY_EMAIL, new Object[]{email}, Integer.class);
}

@Override
public User findById(Integer userId) {
    return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following method has been deprecated and must not be used:

```
public <T> T queryForObject(String sql, @Nullable Object[] args, Class<T> requiredType)
```

Use the following equivalent method instead:

```
 <T> T queryForObject(String sql, Class<T> requiredType, @Nullable Object... args)
```

Example:

```
return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(SQL_COUNT_BY_EMAIL, Integer.class, email);
```